# why was this flag declined

Tags: support

I flagged [a comment on this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30539/what-type-of-corruption-did-trump-campaign-against) which links to the author's other question as "no longer needed".

The author has since erased his other question, but has not erased his own comment linking to his other question.

Why was the "no longer needed" flag declined?

BTW, I think the author was right to erase his other question because it essentially restated his 1st question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I checked the flag, the question was still there. I dismissed it, because the question was indeed related.

According to the timeline of the linked question, the author deleted it, undeleted it, and then deleted it again. I assume I checked the flag while the question was not deleted.